# Who is the guy in the gunner's seat of the Millennium Falcon near the end of The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

You see him for a split second in the final scene with the Final Order and he has kind of a white beard. I can't find any reference online except Nien Nunb from ROJ.

Comment: By the way, Nien Numb was in Rise of Skywalker too, in another such blink-and-you'll-miss-it scene.

Comment: I think Nien Numb has actually been in all of the last three films.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Assuming you mean this person:

[image: Man manning the Falcon's turret]

Then that is [Wedge Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles) originally seen in the Original Trilogy.

[image: Wedge in the Original Trilogy]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102980/discussion-on-answer-by-thelethalcarrot-who-is-the-guy-with-lando-in-the-millenn).

Comment: Fun fact: the actor, Denis Lawson, is Ewan McGregor's uncle.

Comment: Do we know that this character is Wedge?  Is it possible this is another character played by Denis Lawson?

Comment: @Amy it would be odd to have a cameo and have them play a different character but I can try and find something a bit more explicit if you want. IMDb notes the character name and that usually comes from the subtitles I believe.

Comment: @Amy, Denis Lawson as Wedge was listed in the end credits...it was such a quick scene that I made a point to actually confirm that I saw what I saw

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Oh, I absolutely agree.  I can't think of a good example.  He didn't have any dialog (that I recall) nor was he addressed by name.  I don't recall him wearing any military rank insignia in the movie.  I just wanted confirmation.

Comment: I actually saw him, recognized him and let out an audible gasp of excitement when I saw him in the film.  My wife asked what I saw.  I was giddy.

Comment: @RLH Me too!  I was turned to my wife to say "That's Wedge!", but I couldn't say anything...I was too choked up